# Why is my PWA not being recognized and appearing for install?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest.json

I have made a PWA, manifest and service worker and all, and the PWA install (atleast on Chrome) is not appearing. I have read all the requirements and have fufilled them, but still it's not showing the install prompt.

`manifest.json`

```json
{
  "name": "Surplus Learning",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "browser",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "any",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/images/icon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "any",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#333333",
  "background_color": "#333333",
  "short_name": "S L",
  "description": "The best place for students.",
  "dir": "rtl",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "display_override": [
    "browser"
  ],
  "categories": [
    "education",
    "productivity"
  ],
  "prefer_related_applications": false,
  "lang": "en"
}
```

Service Worker

```js
// This is the service worker with the combined offline experience (Offline page + Offline copy of pages)

const CACHE = "pwabuilder-offline-page";

importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js');

const offlineFallbackPage = "offline.html";

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.addEventListener('install', async (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE)
      .then((cache) => cache.add(offlineFallbackPage))
  );
});

if (workbox.navigationPreload.isSupported()) {
  workbox.navigationPreload.enable();
}

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/*'),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: CACHE
  })
);

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
      try {
        const preloadResp = await event.preloadResponse;

        if (preloadResp) {
          return preloadResp;
        }

        const networkResp = await fetch(event.request);
        return networkResp;
      } catch (error) {

        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE);
        const cachedResp = await cache.match(offlineFallbackPage);
        return cachedResp;
      }
    })());
  }
});
```

The site works and serves cached pages but no install prompt is shown. Please help!

Comment: One thing that is also required for the PWA to work is that the site is served with httpS and not http, is it your case ?

Comment: My site runs on Netlify, so yes, https.

Comment: Did you check the installation requirements listed here: [https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation/](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation/)
They vary depending on OS and browser.

Comment: I am mainly targeting Chrome, and I have all the necessary values.

Comment: Can you install it manually via menu or icon? How do other PWA behave / are they installable? (e.g https://fugu-tracker.web.app/) 
I tested the install prompt for the fugu-tracker on my PC (Win 10 Enterprise V 22H2 / Chrome 112) but no prompt appears. While on mobile (Chrome/Android) the prompt appears immediately. Maybe something is off with the install prompt in combination with Win & Chrome. :-/

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome devtools has a tab called application. This tab shows PWA information about your current website and it also shows what causes an app not to be installable. Please take a look at this information.

Comment: I do not have access to this information at this time due to computer restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess then is that the display attribute set to browser is the issue.
Try to set it to

```
"display": "standalone"
```

Just to confirm that it's not the problem.

Comment: was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually linked your manifest like this

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
```

In the `<head>` of your main page. Also make sure you are actually running this from a web server, and not a local file.
You may also want to take a look at this MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

Comment: Does it matter how I end the `<link>`? I put `</link>` instead of the backslash like: `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />`

Comment: `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"></link>` is how I put it*

Comment: According to MDN, you shouldn't add a closing tag, so `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>`

Comment: The problem still persists after changing this

Comment: Are you accessing the page from a server?

Comment: What do you mean by "Are you accessing the page from a server?" Like an IP?

Comment: Yes, effectively any url that doesn't start with `file://`